# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inject'

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I'm having trouble with running a test through PyCharm. Here is the full traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jovicacordas/miniconda3/envs/orqa/bin/orqacli", line 33, in <module>
      sys.exit(load_entry_point('orqa', 'console_scripts', 'orqacli')())
  File "/Users/jovicacordas/fb-projects/test-web-tests/orqa/__init__.py", line 61, in cli
    setup()
  File "/Users/jovicacordas/fb-projects/test-web-tests/orqa/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    import inject
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inject'
```

I already have installed `inject 4.3.1` and when I try to install it again it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: Inject in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.3.1)
```

When I do the pip list, I can see inject being installed in requirements. I'm using a virtual environment.

Comment: you need to make sure that you install in the right python environment: `conda install -n orqa <pkg-name>` or `conda activate orqa` followed by `python -m pip install <pkg-name>`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are installing inject after activating your virtual env.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).